# RL: if an information is included in the reward but not in the state, can it be trained well?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I want to train an agent adjusting scheduling action with the goal of minimizing cost, the reward already includes price change information, is it necessary to input price into state of the neural network?

For example, in a job-shop problem solved using RL, the agent needs to dynamically adjust the matching of jobs and workshops based on real-time electricity prices (assuming different electricity consumption leads to varying costs). Therefore, the neural network requires inputs such as the features of jobs and real-time operating conditions of workshops. I have been contemplating whether to include electricity price information as an input. Even if it is not directly fed as a state input to the neural network, the electricity price information will inevitably be utilized in calculating the reward and participate in network updates.

In my opinion, R can reflect price change. And if I input price as one of the state, I can only input the current price instead of a trace, and train with the same group of price information will influence my test results. Is it right?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It could just be me, but I do not think I understand what you are trying. Could you elaborate by giving an example?

Comment: reward is a function of state and action, you can use any reward based on this